# Update textview on runtime while uploading images to firebase kotlin inside for each loop without freezing ui

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime, firebase-storage

I'm facing a problem while uploading images to firebase. I need to update the uploading count to textview while uploading. But when the uploading starts Ui shows the starting hardcoded value then direct shows the 2nd last and then the last one. What is the best way to update textview during uploading to firebase?

Comment: can you post some code about uploading in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the textView in the addOnSuccessListener.

Something like this:

```
storageRef.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?> {
            textView.setText(count++)
        })
```